Using Linkedin API, are there any sites I can use for testing purposes?
I am trying to test the LinkedIn API endpoints to retrieve posts. However, when creating an app, it requires an organizational site, which I don't have as an individual. Additionally, I can't use the r_member_social permission since access to it is currently not provided. Are there any sites I can use for testing purposes?
If there is a way please let me know.
Thank you.
I have tried for creating an app but as an individual i have limited access to the endpoints.
